# What does it mean that the types have to align in for-comprensions?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Can someone please elaborate what it means when the types have to align with scala for comprehensions?

```
for {
..
..
}
```

If the calls all return Futures then it will be fine?
Just trying to understand when it works and when it doesn't work.

Comment: Remember `for` is just sugar syntax for `flatMap` calls, `flatMap` comes from **Monads** and **Monads** do not compose. So, as you said, all the computations in a single `for` expression have to be done on the same effectual type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For-comprehension desugars to map/flatMap calls so consider their signatures. For example, consider `Option#flatMap`

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

We see `Option`s continue to be involved. Now observe since

```
for {
  a <- Some(41)
  b <- Some(1)
} yield a + b
```

becomes

```
Some(41).flatMap(a => Some(1).map(b => a + b))
```

that means if you tried to mix monadic types inside for-comprehension such as

```
for {
  a <- Some(41)
  b <- Try(1)
} yield a + b
```

then it would desugar to

```
Some(41).flatMap(a => Try(1).map(b => a + b))
                       |
                  types do not align
```

but we already seen that `Option#flatMap` expects `A => Option[B]` not `A => Try[B]`.

One place where it seems as if you can break that rule is when mixing Option with List

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- List(41)
     |   b <- Some(1)
     | } yield (a + b)
val res0: List[Int] = List(42)
```

but this works because `List#flatMap` takes a function from `A` to `IterableOnce` and `Option` has been made `IterableOnce` in Scala 2.13

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => IterableOnce[B])
```

Note the other way around will not work though:

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- Some(41)
     |   b <- List(1)
     | } yield a + b
         b <- List(1)
           ^
On line 3: error: type mismatch;
        found   : List[Int]
        required: Option[?]
```

In general given an effectful type `F[A]` then inside for-comprehension `F` cannot vary unless we are using a subtype, on the other hand `A` can indeed vary.